# Alternative to Motion for streaming video in linux

Tags: linux, video, streaming, webcam, server

I am looking for a simple video streaming program for linux (Raspberry Pi). It just needs to take video from a webcam and stream it in a format that can be embedded in a web page (served with NodeJS on the same RPi).

The only reason I'm not using Motion is I'm having [difficulty setting it up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331666/motion-stops-streaming-on-movement-and-no-logs-produced), and I want to see if something else is easier.

Comment: Tons of how-tos incl. software recommendations on [a quick search for "Raspi webcam"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=raspi+webcam) – ranging from simple webcams to DIY home alarm systems. Tried any of those? [One of them](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-remote-webcam/) includes a tutorial on setting up Motion, by the way, which sounds pretty easy and straight-forward.

Comment: Izzy - thanks. Yes I've tried tonnes of them. But I've just managed to get mjpg-streamer working. It was painful, but got there in the end with the help of this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=164539#p164539

Comment: Would you consider this (with a few more details) to be an answer to your question? If so, don't hesitate to present it in full :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So [as per this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=164539#p164539) but with some condensing and adjustments, first run these commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install git libv4l-dev libjpeg8-dev imagemagick cmake -y
git clone git@github.com:jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer.git ~/mjpg-streamer
cd ~/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental
make USE_LIBV4L2=true clean all
make DESTDIR=/usr install
```

Although I'm not sure the last line worked for me, I presume it all worked without it. I think it should have put files in the right places (e.g. so executables do not need full paths specified - so instead in the command below I specified the full paths for all files).

Start the server:

```
~/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental/mjpg_streamer -i "~/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental/input_uvc.so -f 15 -r 320x240" -o "~/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental/output_http.so -p 8090 -w ./www"
```

And if you're having trouble with something already using the webcam, (e.g. if `motion` didn't exit cleanly, do the following and repeat the above command:

```
fuser /dev/video0
```

which will give output like this:

> /dev/video0:         12324m

Then run this to kill whatever's using the webcam:

```
kill -9 12324
```

Finally to view the video, navigate to this address, substituting the IP address or URL of your server:

```
http://192.168.0.12:8090/?action=stream
```

And to embed the video in a webpage, simply add this to the HTML:

```
<img src="http://192.168.0.12:8090/?action=stream"/>
```

As a side note, when running the video streaming server, you might want to change the frames per second by changing the argument after `-f`. It seems it has to be a figure that is supported by the webcam; an unsupported figure will in theory be coerced by `mjpeg-streamer` to a supported one, but it failed to stream when I set it to `10`, for example. The same goes for resolution; only `320x240` and `640x480` worked for me.

Comment: Very clear and concise answer - very nice!

Answer (score 1):

I use **[VLC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/667/is-it-possible-to-install-vlc)** for streaming.

This works with the [Raspicam](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/README.md):

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -n | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8090}' :demux=h264
```

But I prefer streaming via rtsp (you can then use VLC again for watching)

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -n | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264
```

Good tutorial for Raspberry PI can be found [here](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-hardware/raspberry-pi-camera/streaming-video-using-vlc-player).

If you use another webcam instead of the Raspicam, you need to change the command to this (assuming the camera is recognized by v4l2):

```
cvlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8090}' :demux=h264
```

Other Useful links you may wish to read:

- [RTSP Server](http://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/rtsp-server/)
- [HOWTO - Create a Raspberry Pi IP Camera with RTSP server.](https://random-notes-of-a-sysadmin.blogspot.com.au/2015/05/howto-create-raspberry-pi-ip-camera.html)

Comment: I edited your answer, just added some formatting.

Comment: I had no idea VLC could be used for this! +1